# mod rewrite doing something weird

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`http://localhost/clean_urls/user/whtffgh` redirect fine to this `http://localhost/clean_urls/user/whtffgh/` (pretty much anything I put there works).

`http://localhost/clean_urls/user/cohen` however, redirects to this
`http://localhost/clean/` and I have no idea why. It should just add a `/`

Heres my .htaccess code

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /clean_urls/user/$1/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteBase /clean_urls/user/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?user=$1


</ifModule>
```

UPDATE:

The code works besides when I put cohen as the username. The second part of the .htaccess file is making `user/index.php?user=username` look like `user/username` so its just a $_GET variable that looks nice in the url and is SEO friendly (apparently).

I am just learning this stuff and making a webapp to try it out so not really sure where its going but I do think I will need another variable on the end. `http:://localhost/clean_urls/user/fred/someverb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand what the RewriteBase directive is used for.  It helps the rewrite engine in a "per directory" context to convert the relative URIs to the correct filename equivalent.

You should only have **one** RewriteBase directive per `.htaccess` file.  The rewrite engine by default will use the lowest `.htaccess` file on the path with the `RewriteEngine On` directive set.

So in DOCroot (that is the directory where a "GET /xxx" is mapped to, this should be

```
RewriteBase /
```

If your `.htaccess` file is in `DOCroot/clean_urls/user` then it should have

```
RewriteBase /clean_urls/user/
```

How do you want to decode URIs of the form `http:://localhost/fred` or are you only wanting do process URIs of the form `http:://localhost/clean_urls/user/fred/`.  What about `http:://localhost/clean_urls/user/fred/someverb`?

Let me know and where you are putting you `.htaccess` then I can give you the right content.

Comment: I added an update to the question clarifying what was going wrong.

Comment: But did you understand and act on my point of not having two bases in the same .htaccess?  Split them as I suggest.

Comment: I get what you mean now. Ill split them up and see if it works.